# Error - bind failed: Address already in use

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

I use the shaka packager to create a .mpd file from the live stream. For that, I used the following command to packaging stream.

```
packager \ 'in=udp://127.0.0.1:40000,stream=audio,init_segment=audio_init.mp4,segment_template=audio_$Number$.m4s' \ 'in=udp://127.0.0.1:40000,stream=video,init_segment=h264_480p_init.mp4,segment_template=h264_480p_$Number$.m4s' \ 
--mpd_output h264_live.mpd
```

And I executed this command to generate an SDP file.

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop 100 -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:11111 -sdp_file saved_sdp_file -acodec copy -vn -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:11112
```

After that, I executed the following command to get a stream using the SDP file.

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist "file,rtp,udp" -i saved_sdp_file -vcodec h264 -tune zerolatency -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:40000
```

There was an error when I used the above command. The error is shown below:
please, help me to solve this issue.

[image: the error]